# Repository pattern: Limitation, purpose , and benefits

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am new to repository pattern, and I come up the following questions:

1. What is/are the purpose of repository pattern?
2. What is/are the limitation of repository pattern?
3. What is/are the benefits of repository pattern?
4. Do the methods below should be exposed in the repository pattern?

---

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery(){
    return _objectSet;
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(){
    return GetQuery().AsEnumerable();
}

public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate){
    return _objectSet.Where(predicate);
}

public T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate){
    return _objectSet.Single(predicate); 
}

public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate){
    return _objectSet.First(predicate);
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What is/are the purpose of repository pattern?

To abstract away the data source to reduce complexity. By doing so the caller do not have to have any knowledge about the data source or it's quirks. They just know that they can invoke the repository and get information from an arbitary data source.

> 2.What is/are the limitation of repository pattern?

It's only used to abstract away the data source.

A soft limit is that people find it hard to understand how to design the repository classes. It's common that people make the repositories to generic which in turn leaks DB implementation to the invoker, thus forcing the caller to have DB specific knowlegde (or OR/M knowledge). Those implementations are seriously flawed and provide no benefit over using OR/Ms directly.

> 3.What is/are the benefits of repository pattern?

Less complex code. The caller get's less complex since they only have to invoke a method in the repository to fetch and store information in the data source. And the Data Access Layer get's less complex sinvce the repositories only focuses on retreiving and storing information.

> 4.Do the methods below should be exposed in the repository pattern?

No. `IQueryable<T>` leaks DB specific information. You need for instance to know how the OR/M handles translates LINQ to `IN` SQL clauses and how the OR/M is configured for lazy/eager loading.

To reduce complexity the repository should communicate what kind of queries it support. Using `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate` is like saying ***throw anything at me and I'll try to handle it***. Won't work very well. Again. Take the `IN` clause as an example. The LINQ statement for it varies between different OR/Ms.

Using expressions also move the responsibility of constructing correct queries to the caller. That means that the unit tests for the caller also have to include tests for validating that the caller makes correct queries. i.e. more complex tests.

Comment: If Repository contains method like GetCarByNumberofVechile() it looks that my Business logic is inside repository. If I further on added GetCarByNumberOfHorsePower() that is also Business logic.Finally Business logic layer looks like decorator. I think that better solution is to write Business logic in a Business layer, but in repostiory write code that translates query from BLL(GetCarByNumberofVechile()) to storage specific language (it can be simple txt)

Comment: No it's not business logic. BL is some sort of computation. Where you do a query against a specific state attribute (horse power) is a simple retrieval where you compare the attribute value.

Comment: I didn't understand you, really. Business analyst told me : "get cars by number of vechile" so for me this is a business logic. Also, BL is GetById, and so on. Maybe, we need to conclude what is BL?

Comment: You definition becomes quite impractical as you either need to fetch all records to be able to do the filter in the BL or use LINQ (which is an leaky abstraction when applied to SQL). A middle ground would be to combine the repository pattern with the specification pattern.

Comment: I agree with you in specification pattern. IMO repository should have one method that accepts specification, so in BL I can build specification (Business logic) and then pass to the repositoy method. How specification will be "translated" to fetch data is on repository.

Comment: I prefer to chose the solution that works best for the current project. Sometimes it's the specification pattern and sometimes it's putting the query methods in the repository. You also have to weight factors as complexity and maintainability. Always choosing the "right" solution seldom works.