# Using Asp.Net to create an Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am creating a web page in asp.net C# where users enter their information like employee_id, name, skill_name, skill_category, skill_proficiency etc.

When they click the "submit" button, I want an Excel file (.xls) to be generated on the server where all data gets stored. As users continue to enter data, the Excel file must be populated.

I know using a DB here is a must, but I have been told to strictly use Excel file as the scope of project is very small.

Any starting point to help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

(no product placement)

In our projects where we have simular requirements we use a third party tool like [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/products/cells/net). I have used it in about 7 projects and i like it very much.

The costs from about $1000 is relatively cheap in comparison with your daily salary. 
(Of course there is a trial version for 30 days too)

[image: Aspose.Cells Pricing]

In your case i would suggest to do the following steps:

1. Create a website where users can insert their data
2. Store this data in a database
3. Implement a excel export functionality

The export (with Aspose.Cells in mind) is relatively simple:

```
// Load template XLSX
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(@"C:\temp\YourTemplate.xlsx");

// get the first worksheet
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

// some logic to dump your data from database to the worksheet
ExportDataFromDbToWorksheet(worksheet);

//Saving the Excel file
workbook.Save(@"C:\temp\Export.xlsx");
```

Give it a try.
Buying a library (nomatter which) is in most cases much more cheaper than implementing by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For projects like this, you need to start thinking about which external resources you may need. As soon as I read this question, I began to think how I think when I am programming. "Okay, I need a Excel-file library or API to import into my project which has methods that I can then use to read/write to Excel spreadsheet files." You then take that and begin your search. I searched for you and I found two options, but there are probably others out there:

1. [Excel Library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/excellibrary/)
2. [Spreadsheet Light](http://spreadsheetlight.com/download/)

The important part here is not the specific libraries, but that you are thinking in the right terms. For example, I once had to write an application in C# which wrote Microsoft Word .docx files... C# can't do this on its own so I searched for "Write .docx files with C#" and eventually found and used a library called DocX.

Having said this, once you get one of those libraries and successfully import it into your project, you will need to read the docs and play with the methods a bit until you become comfortable with how to create, write to, save, and close a file. Now, all you will need to do is reference it in your ASP.NET application, new up the object and write the business logic in the appropriate spot. You could create an abstraction like a [repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900485/repository-pattern-limitation-purpose-and-benefits) which implements the Excel file logic that you just learned. A repo pattern would abstract your business logic/core program away from the library so that you could replace the library with a new/different one without affecting your own program's code. That should get you started!